# EIN inline plot is working in GUI window but not in terminal mode (-nw)

Tags: ein

EIN matplotlib can plot inline image at GUI but not in terminal mode (-nw)

in terminal mode, output is just a dot '.'
Is there way I can plot in terminal mode?

I already turn on Ein:Output Area Inlined Images toggle and ein:polymode

I am using Terminal on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1
And Ein version 20230827.325

Anyone know how to display plot in terminal mode?

[image]

Comment: I don't know EIN, but… is showing inline images even supported in terminal mode? That sounds complicated, although does not mean it's not possible with ASCII-art…